# CLR/CLI - How do I set a custom icon to my form application?

Tags: c#, forms, c++-cli, clr

I have seen few answers about this but none worked for me.

Using Visual Studio 2022, clr/cli project, code in *.cpp file.

I created custom icon *"MyIcon.ico"*,
I want this to be my application icon.
I understand I need to use `ResourceManager::GetObject` (?) and assign the icon to `myForm->Icon`.

Something like:
`MyForm->Icon = MyApp::Resources::ResourceManager::GetObject( "MyIcon.ico");`

This does not work or compile.
Can someone give me a simple example on how I do this?
Please keep in mind that this is a CPP file in a *clr/cli* project. Not pure C#.

Thanks, Pazo

Answer (score 0):

Eventaully I managed to solve this problem using WIN32 API, as the clr/cli `ResourceManager` object did not work for me. I could not find the correct way to construct it. Microsoft documentation on the web contains many examples for C#, but none for clr/cli.

```
//  1. Load the resource from the executable using WIN32 API:
HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
HICON   hIcon   = ::LoadIcon( hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MY_ICON));

//  2.  Convert the C icon-handle to C# icon object:
System::Drawing::Icon^ rIcon = System::Drawing::Icon::FromHandle( System::IntPtr( hIcon));

//  3.  Set icon to form:
theForm->Icon = rIcon;
```